# PHP - How to iterate through JSON arrays within JSON arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having problems with the following code:

```
$invoice_customers = [];
foreach ($new['data'] as $key=>$display) {

if ($display['customer'] == $customer){
    $invoice_customers[$key]['customer'] = $display['source']['customer'];
    $invoice_customers[$key]['name'] = $display['source']['name'];
    $invoice_customers[$key]['amount'] = $display['amount'];
    $invoice_customers[$key]['refunded'] = $display['refunded'];
    $invoice_customers[$key]['last4'] = $display['source']['last4'];
    $invoice_customers[$key]['id'] = $display['id'];
    $invoice_customers[$key]['created'] = $display['created'];
}
}

echo json_encode($invoice_customers);
```

This returns:

```
 {"3":
    {"customer":"xxxxx","name":"Testtt Test","amount":100,"refunded":false,"last4":"4242","id":"x","created":1500342123},
 "4xxx":
    {"customer":"xxxxx","name":"Testtt Test","amount":100,"refunded":false,"last4":"4242","id":"xxxx","created":1500340979}}
```

As you can see I have the main array with some arrays within. I would like to know how to access only the arrays within the main array? IE: Something like this:

```
{"customer":"xxxxx","name":"Testtt Test","amount":100,"refunded":false,"last4":"xxxx","id":"x","created":1500342123},
{"customer":"xxxxx","name":"Testtt Test","amount":100,"refunded":false,"last4":"xxxx","id":"xxxx","created":1500340979}
```

Comment: You have to decode that again into a hierarchical array and then iterate over the elements of the outer array. Or access or search a specific element, just as you like.

Comment: Use json_decode to get a json object and then be able to traverse it like $invoice_customers->["3"]->name

Comment: You build a PHP data structure, you encode it as JSON and then you want what? You already have everything in `$invoice_customers`. Why would you want to *"access arrays within the main array"* in a string?

Answer (score 2):

Your existing object

```
var myobject ={
   "3":{
      "customer":"xxxxx",
      "name":"Testtt Test",
      "amount":100,
      "refunded":false,
      "last4":"4242",
      "id":"x",
      "created":1500342123
   },
   "4xxx":{
      "customer":"xxxxx",
      "name":"Testtt Test",
      "amount":100,
      "refunded":false,
      "last4":"4242",
      "id":"xxxx",
      "created":1500340979
   }
}
```

Can be accessed like `myobject['3'], myobject['4xxx']`

And use below one if you want to create array

```
json_encode(array_values($invoice_customers));
```

Will produce, and can be accessed using index `0,1....` so on like `myarray[0], myarray[1] ...`

```
var myarray =[
   {
      "customer":"xxxxx",
      "name":"Testtt Test",
      "amount":100,
      "refunded":false,
      "last4":"xxxx",
      "id":"x",
      "created":1500342123
   },
   {
      "customer":"xxxxx",
      "name":"Testtt Test",
      "amount":100,
      "refunded":false,
      "last4":"xxxx",
      "id":"xxxx",
      "created":1500340979
   }
]
```

***Here is Demo***

```js
var myobject ={
   "3":{
      "customer":"xxxxx",
      "name":"Testtt Test",
      "amount":100,
      "refunded":false,
      "last4":"4242",
      "id":"x",
      "created":1500342123
   },
   "4xxx":{
      "customer":"xxxxx",
      "name":"Testtt Test",
      "amount":100,
      "refunded":false,
      "last4":"4242",
      "id":"xxxx",
      "created":1500340979
   }
};
var myarray =[
   {
      "customer":"xxxxx",
      "name":"Testtt Test",
      "amount":100,
      "refunded":false,
      "last4":"xxxx",
      "id":"x",
      "created":1500342123
   },
   {
      "customer":"xxxxx",
      "name":"Testtt Test",
      "amount":100,
      "refunded":false,
      "last4":"xxxx",
      "id":"xxxx",
      "created":1500340979
   }
];

// access object
console.log(myobject['3']['customer']);
console.log(myobject['3'].name);

// access array
console.log(myarray[0]['customer']);
console.log(myarray[0].name);
```